# Should a React component use (fixed) values not on state or props?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and trying to understand if what I am doing is an anti-pattern. I have a component that renders a modal that contains a `<select>` input. The options available in that `<select>` come from a service - they will probably never change but I want those values to live in the service not be hard coded on the component UI. I am tempted to assign this options array to `this`, rather than `this.state`, since it will not change. I could assign the options via props, but that seems to be asking the parent component to do too much - it shouldn't have to know about those values.

So the basic question is, is it ever valid in React to have some data stored directly on `this` instead of on state or props?

Comment: it's okay, react does not care.

Comment: As long as you don't need it to trigger a render, then setting on the component shouldn't matter. However, if you need it to recognize a change to state, I suggest using `this.state` with `this.setState`. Really depends on how your components are laid out but both are valid.

Comment: for that reason we use `import {connect} from 'react-redux` function

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I don't follow. What has redux connect to do with this question?

Comment: @Dom - thanks. I'll accept that as an answer if you care to make it one (cheap win ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to handle your scenario, and it is very common in React development. In my opinion, data that has fixed value (that doesn't change over time, eg: date-format, certain select options (gender), etc.) should be better stored in a certain place in your application, so that it can be better managed and maintained (also, that will take out the constant values from the rendering logic in your components). I've always kept my components clean from constants/fixed values (moved them into `constants.js`) and functions (moved them into `utils/` folder and unit test them) out from the component files so that they can be easily read and maintain.

Hoping this below information can help you:

```
// Storing them into one single file
import { services } from '../constants';

// Global constants - when you're pretty sure it will never change;
// using global constants also make it easier to update from the top of the component file.
const SERVICES = [
  'services-a',
  'services-b',
];

// Storing in redux store
@connect(state => ({ services: state.services }))
export default class App extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    services: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  }

  // Using the getter method; I mainly use this when I want to process some information with props data
  // NOTE: Some people might think that this is an anti-pattern in React
  get services() {
    const { someRelevantDetailsFromProps } = this.props;
    // process and return
    return someRelevantDetailsFromProps.map();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select>
        {/* Importing from constant file */}
        { services.map(service => <option value={service}>{service}</option>) }

        {/* Using class getter method */}
        { this.services.map(service => <option value={service}>{service}</option>) }

        {/* Using redux store */}
        { this.props.services.map(service => <option value={service}>{service}</option>) }

        {/* Using global contant */}
        { SERVICES.map(service => <option value={service}>{service}</option>) }
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can store your own variables in the class even they don't update by state through. There is no anti-pattern.

Most anti-patterns and articles about anti-patterns are to make you avoid the unknown problems and side effects. But if you really know how to works React then you can play as you want. I think to use your own way might be awful with problems but it's best learning way of the something. I mean, don't barrier yourself to lose your creativity. Already you going to find true way on the way.

Each anti-pattern has the true pattern, also. So you always have a chance. An example; to get "prop value" from parent component for put "initial state" in constructor is anti-pattern. Because it never update. But if you use getDerivedStateFromProps life cycle method to update new state value from props then it won't be anti-pattern.

An example i used many times that logic to avoid unmounted component renders by state:

```
updateState()
{
  // To avoid unmounted setState for unfinished process
  if (this.mounted)
  {
    this.setState(...);
  }
}
```

Already people love **React** because it's just Javascript even it's have JSX though.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component
{
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)
  {
    // We always getting actual state when parent change the prop value
    // Now it became true pattern with keep up-to-date the state from props
    if (props.defaultSelectValue !== state.selectValue)
    {
      return {
        selectValue: props.defaultSelectValue,
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    const { defaultSelectValue } = this.props;

    this.state =
    {
      selectValue: defaultSelectValue,
    };

    this.cache =
    {
      SelectComponent: ({ items }) => // We used arrow function to don't lose the this scope
      {
        const { selectValue } = this.state; // this will be always actual state

        return (
         <select value={selectValue}>
           <option value="0">Yes</option>
           <option value="1">No</option>
         </select>
        );
      },
    };
  }

  render()
  {
    const { SelectComponent } = this.cache;

    return (
     <SelectComponent />
    );
  }
}
```

So if you know what you are doing, then there is no anti-pattern.