# Should we use class variable in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I tend to avoid using class variable as much as possible, likely 99% of my codes are done with `state`. Always have an impression that, we should avoid using this because `React` re-render UI when there are change to `state` or `props` only.

Recently my colleague started using **class variable**, for storing some **hardcoded value** like following. I don't see why we can't store this hardcoded value within state, although the **value actually never gets updated** in app. And this type of value assigning still works.

```
this.Arr = [
      { option: 'Product'},
      { option: 'Technical'},
      { option: 'Enquiry'},
      { option: 'Report'},
    ];
```

So, should we use class variable in react native? What's your supporting argument here?

### Update

After some further readings from the following questions, I came into a conclusion of..

Readings:

1. [ReactJS - What is difference between component state and class variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54428219/reactjs-what-is-difference-between-component-state-and-class-variable)
2. [Should a React component use (fixed) values not on state or props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281688/should-a-react-component-use-fixed-values-not-on-state-or-props)

Conclusion:

1. As always, keep variable that possibly mutate inside State Variable.
2. It's fine to store hardcoded value with Class Variable. However, it might make sense to move them to a constant file where you read all the fix value from there.
3. Using Class Variable is not an anti-pattern of ReactJS/ReactNative. Since the value does not require UI to re-render, hence storing in Class Variable is not an issue.

---

Appreciate anyone to comment further. Thanks.

Comment: State is meant for stuff that *changes*, or isn't absolutely static. There's nothing inherently wrong with putting something unchangeable into state, it just doesn't make a whole lot of sense, and confusing code is even worse than inefficient code. I'd avoid it if I were you.

Comment: Correct, that's my understanding as well. So the point made here is confusing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this variable is something that will never change and doesn't depend on anything that exists in the scope of your component, I'd suggest storing it as a constant outside of your component instead.

If you do need to generate it based on things that are in the scope of your component, you need to store it either as a state or as a class variable.

I would recommend that you store it as a state *only* if you need to update your UI when that variable changes (with setState). If you don't need that, it's better to store as a class variable. And the reason is that if you store it on a state, without actually requiring a UI update when that variable changes, you will end up causing unnecessary re-renders, that may be expensive.

Also, storing something that is by definition not a state, inside a state, is more confusing in my opinion than storing it separately as a class variable.

Btw, If you're working in a project that allows you to move from class components to hooks, I'd strongly suggest so.

Comment: What do you mean by expensive when that variable changes? What's expensive here? Like I said, we know for sure this is a hardcoded value (for this component), it will never get change.

Comment: If you store something in the state, and use setState to change it, it will cause a re-render, that is what is expensive. If you're never going to change that ever, there's no reason to store it in the state - because by definition it's not a state. I think that it's more confusing to store it in a state in that case, so I'd avoid it.

Comment: I've already said, it's a hardcoded value. It's not going to change.

Comment: Agree with the comment here, I think we should store constant value outside of component instead and keeping mutation value in state variable.

Comment: Currently I am moving from functional components to class components but here I read that you are suggesting to use functional components. Why so? It is hard to manage states in func. comp. while class comp. allows simple access to lifecycle